# How do i see that status of MYSQL execution when using mysqli prepare?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli( '127.0.0.1', 'root', 'P', '_db' );


{
$xkey=$key2+1;
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE blablabla mysql
$stmt->bind_param('ii', $xkey, $strings);
$stmt->execute();
}
}
```

And i need to echo different things based on if it failed or not. I tried this

```
if(!$stmt){
then
//do
}else{
//do
}
```

But it didnt work.

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php

> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

```
$status = $stmt->execute();

if ($status === true) {
    // good
}
else {
    // bad
}
```